# Mark Outlook TaskItem as Completed in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm creating an Outlook Task with status marked as Completed

```cs
                    if (task != null)
                    {
                        task.Subject = mi.Subject;
                        task.Status = (Outlook.OlTaskStatus)2; //Status remains 0
                        task.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
                        task.Save();
                    }
```

`Outlook.OlTaskStatus` is an `enum` and value of Complete state is 2. But it remains 0 and task is not marked as completed. Number of ways i've tried till to mark task as completed are as following:

1. `task.Status = Outlook.OlTaskStatus.olTaskComplete;`
2. `task.MarkComplete();`
3. `task.Complete=true;`
4. `task.Status = (Outlook.OlTaskStatus)2;`

Nothing appears to be effective and `Status` is still `0`. Can someone please suggest the right way to mark an outlook task `Complete` ?

Answer (score 0):

The [TaskItem.MarkComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.taskitem.markcomplete) method marks the task as completed and sets `PercentComplete` to "100%", `Complete` to true, and `DateCompleted` to the current date.

I think you need to change the order in which properties and methods are called:

```
if (task != null)
{
    task.Subject = mi.Subject;
    task.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
    task.Save();
   
    // the following call should set the status
    task.MarkComplete();
    task.Save();
}
```

Comment: I tried the above sequence of calls but it still doesn't work. Somehow, the task object's ```Complete``` attribute is having no effect of whatever I try to change it.

Comment: I created a new simple vsto project in VS and wrote the same lines. It works in that project but not in original one. Even all other methods which I mentioned in the question is working in the new project. It appears VS is playing in between.